# How to fix this sublime 3 bug?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Sublime3 to write Python code.However when I create a code like this:

```
test=input("Example: ")
if test=="A":
   print("It is A!")
```

And try to run it, it asks me for input but when i type the input, instead of printing what I said it does nothing.However when I run the same code in the terminal, it works perfectly.What should I do to fix this?

Comment: IDE consoles rarely support `input()`. This is not a bug, just a limitation of such consoles.

Comment: Yeah it actually supports input but it doesn't do what I say after the input

Comment: It only outputs the text `Example:`. It doesn't actually take any input.

Comment: Yeah this is actually what it does, although every single one text editor i have used before, supported input

Comment: That's a bold claim, but won't make Sublime Text 3 take input, sorry.